# Java while loop until user enters a value of 0

Tags: java

Having trouble creating a while loop that continues reading users input values, until the value of 0 is entered. Then the average of all the values will be calculated and printed at the end. Here is part of my coding but this is incorrect. Just showing you the way I perceive the problem.

```
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String inputValues;

int sum = 0;
double average;

inputValues = input.readLine();
String[] intValues = inputValues.split("\\s+");


// This is incorrect but this is the idea I am looking for
while(intValues != 0) {       
    sum += Integer.parseInt(intValues[i]);
}

// Here the average is calculated as a double, and printed below. 
average = Double.parseDouble(sum / intValues.length);
System.out.print(average);
```

Comment: As you mentioned the problem is at this line: while(intValues != 0) {  Why does your input  have to be an array? Can you also add an example input expected from your user?

Comment: It does not compile... `while(intValues != 0)` should most likely be `while(inputValues != 0)`. Also, `parseDouble` cannot be applied to `int`. And who is `i` ? What's with your code ? Did you test it ?

Comment: @Dici Please check the code he pasted it already has a comment above the while loop that the code is incorrect.

Comment: @AnupamSaini hum that's right, but the `parseDouble` line is also wrong. Nevermind...

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try `Scanner` here.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
while(scanner.hasNextInt()) {
  int num = scanner.nextInt();
  if (num == 0)
    break;

  sum += num;
  count += 1;
}

System.out.println("Average: " + sum/count);
```

For `BufferedReader` case:

```
int i = 0;
while(intValues[i] != 0) {// assuming all the number were entered in one line with space as delimiter    
    sum += Integer.parseInt(intValues[i++]);
}

System.out.println("Average: " + sum/intValues.length);
```

Comment: Specifically trying to use the BufferedReader for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

You could start by using a `Scanner` class, which will allow you to process the input, for example...

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int sum = 0;
boolean exit = false;
do {
    String input = scanner.nextLine();
    Scanner check = new Scanner(input);
    if (check.hasNextInt()) {
        int value = check.nextInt();
        if (value == 0) {
            exit = true;
        } else {
            sum += value;
        }
    }
} while (!exit);
```

`hasNextInt` avoids the possible exception that `Integer.parseInt` will generate if you try and parse a none-numerical value.

You could also use a `while (check.hasNextInt()) {...` to loop of multiple input values from a single line of input...

You can check the documentation for [`Scanner` here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

If you wish to continue using the `BufferedReader`, you could use the some stye of logic...

```
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

int sum = 0;
int count = 0;
double average;

try {
    boolean exit = false;
    do {
        System.out.print(">> ");
        String inputValues = input.readLine();
        String[] intValues = inputValues.split("\\s+");
        for (String value : intValues) {
            if ("0".equals(value.trim())) {
                exit = true;
                break;
            } else {
                count++;
                System.out.println(value);
                sum += Integer.parseInt(value);
            }
        }
    } while (!exit);

    System.out.println(sum + " / " + count);
    average = (double) sum / (double) count;
    System.out.print(average);
} catch (IOException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
} catch (NumberFormatException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
Boolean flag=true;
int counte=0;
while(flag)
{
          inputValues = input.readLine();
          if(Integer.parseInt(inputValues)==0)
          {
                flag=false;
                continue;
           }
         counter++; // used to take avarage
         sum+=Integer.parseInt(inputValues);
 }
```

And After Loop is finished calculate the **avarage**

Comment: You'll need to track a counter somehow to calculate the average.

Comment: `Boolean` is little excessive and you typically, you'll want to complete the loop at once, so a `do-while` would be more appropriate loop - just saying...