# how to capture enter key when asking for integer input

Tags: java

How do you capture the enter key when using hasNextInt()?  I have the following code and am trying to exit gracefully if the user just enters the return key.  In the example below I was expecting to get back -9, but the program just hangs on the hasNextInt() line

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class InputInt{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        InputInt x = new InputInt();
        System.out.println(x.enterInt());
    }
    public int enterInt(){
        int myInt = -9;
        boolean isValid = false;
        String lf = "";
        
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        while(!isValid){
            System.out.print("please enter an integer: ");
            if(kb.hasNextInt()){
                myInt = kb.nextInt();
                isValid = true;
            }else{
                lf = kb.nextLine();
                if (lf.length() == 0)isValid = true;
                
            }            
        }        
        return myInt;
    }
   
}
```

Comment: Personally, I'd use one `Scanner` with `nextLine` to read the input from the user and then a second `Scanner` to parse it for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28260016/java-while-loop-until-user-enters-a-value-of-0/28260037#28260037), but for some reason, people don't like that approach, alternatively, you could use `nextLine` to get the next line of input and simple try using `Integer.parseInt` and handle the exception, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71551770/java-and-nextint-what-if-user-just-hits-enter/71552149#71552149)

Comment: @MadProgrammer That's an interesting approach. Even though I think `hasNextInt()` and `nextInt()` still use `Integer.parseInt` and `NumberFormatException` under the covers, it is a clean approach.

Comment: @DavidConrad The problem with `hasNextInt` in this context, is how it handles the enter key, it doesn't seem to "consume" it or produce an error (at least not immediately).  If you're scanning a file or something, then it's probably okay.  I also prefer not to use `try-catch` as a flow control mechanism, but that's me :P

Comment: @DCR This kind of thing does get asked a bit, but finding a "clean" solution isn't always easy, I prefer to make use of some kind of re-usable workflow if I can, [for example](https://gist.github.com/RustyKnight/93f07a59b1b17af7da9d7a5f15aa79a1).  This is just a conceptual idea and one which you could grow more ideas from if you wanted

Comment: @MadProgrammer Right, but my point is, it's still using `try-catch` as a flow control mechanism, it's just hidden inside the standard library code.

Answer (score 3):

When asking for user input, always use `nextLine()`, which clears the input buffer (including the trailing newline), then check/parse the input for correctness:

```
while (true) {
    System.out.print("Please enter an integer: ");
    String input = kb.nextLine();
    if (input.matches("\\d{1,8}")) {
        myInt = Integer.parseInt(input);
        isValid = true;
        break;
    } else if (input.ieEmpty()) {
        break;
    } else {
        System.out.print("1 to 8 digits only please, or blank to exit.");
}
```

The final else is optional, but a nice touch.

The limiting of input to up to 8 digits means you'll never get a error on parsing. To allow every valid integer using regex, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20793792/256196) (it's ugly, so viewer discretion is advised).

Note also the more succinct and conventional `while (true)` with `break` combination, which obviates the need for overloading the `isValid` variable, which now means the user entered a valid integer.

To also allow negative numbers, use instead:

```
if (input.matches("-?\\d{1,8}"))
```